# How to set a command alias that will be respected in a shebang

Tags: linux, php, bash, alias, bashrc

I run multiple versions of PHP on my Linux server. I've added an alias in my bashrc to point the `php` command to a specific version `alias php='/usr/bin/php7.3'`.

This works as expected when I execute a PHP script actually using the php command eg `php myscript.php`

However, if I make `myscript.php` an executable and put the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env php` at the top, it executes the script with the default version of PHP, and does not use the alias defined in my bashrc.

I know I can change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/php7.3`, but I need this globally, rather than file by file.

Is it possible to set an alias for the `php` command which is respected in the shebang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to set an alias for the php command which is respected in the shebang?

No because shebang is parsed by kernel which doesn't know or care about your
shell-specific aliases and environment such as $PATH (this is why you
have to provide a full path in the shebang). What you can do is to
make `php` a symlink to the specific php version and prepend the directory that contains it to your
PATH so that it will be picked by `env`.

Comment: I did as you suggested and whilst it works when running the `php` command, its not getting picked up by `env`. `$PATH` contains the directory with my symlink and running `env` shows the same path, yet the version of PHP run from the shebang is still the default one.

Comment: @Dom: did you add the directory that contains the symlink *before* an old value of PATH: `PATH=<dir>:$PATH`?

Comment: Yes. `PATH` in my bashrc looks like this `PATH=~/bin:$PATH:~/.composer` symlink to required version of PHP created in a `bin` subdirectory of my home directory.

Comment: @Dom: and what does `type -a php` say?

Comment: Four lines: php is aliased to `/usr/bin/php7.3'`, `/var/www/dom/bin/php`, `/usr/bin/php` and `/bin/php`

Comment: So no mention of `php is /home/<user>/bin/php` - something is
wrong. Post output of `ls -Al ~/bin/php`

Comment: Home directory for user is set to `/var/www/dom`, so that's the second one.

Comment: Ok so what does `env php --version` say? Is this the version you want to use?

Comment: Says its 7.3, which is where I've symlinked to. The default is 8.0 and that's what I'm getting when I when I run with the shebang.

Comment: So how are you starting the PHP scripts? Do you use some graphical file manager? Can you run the script in the command line?

Comment: I am running the script from the command line in bash. Just doing `./myscript.php`

Comment: And your shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env php` and you run like that: `./script.php` or provide a full path: `/path/to/script.php`?

Comment: I deleted and recreated my script and I'm getting a different result now. I think it may have been working all along and I had a typo in my shebang. So sorry to have wasted your time and thank you for helping.